# SVG translate seems to behave different in Chrome/Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, svg, transform, chromium

https://jsfiddle.net/Lpfa9umq/

Code:

```
<svg>
    <symbol>
        <circle id="circle1" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
        <circle id="circle2" cx="25" cy="25" r="10" stroke="red" fill="red" stroke-width="1" />
    </symbol>
</svg>
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <use xlink:href="#circle1" />
    <svg width="50" height="50" transform="translate(20, 10)">
        <use xlink:href="#circle2" />
    </svg>
</svg>
```

The transform attribute is applied in Firefox, but not in Chrome/Chromium, why? Am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<svg>` within `<svg>` is confusing the browser. Instead use `<g>` tag.

```
<g transform="translate(20, 10)">
    <use xlink:href="#circle2" />
</g>
```

Comment: `<use xlink:href="#circle2" transform="translate(20, 10)" />` works but not recommended since you may want to group `circle2` with other objects under same transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works. But why is svg inside svg "confusing"?

Comment: Could be a Chrome bug but have you tried adding some SVG tags (eg: `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio`, `x` & `y` for inline SVG). First time seeing this bug, I dont use `symbol` too often as `use` fails on some Safari version.

Answer (score 10):

In SVG 1.1 `<svg>` elements do not accept transform attributes. In SVG 2 it is [proposed that they should](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#SVGElement).

Chrome and Firefox are experimenting with implementing proposed parts of the SVG 2 specification. Some things are implemented only by Firefox, and others only by Chrome. Many features are implemented by both and some by neither.

In this particular case Firefox has implemented the SVG 2 feature but Chrome has not.

You can achieve the same result in browsers that do not support this SVG 2 feature either by replacing the `<svg>` element by a `<g>` element or by creating an `<svg>` child element on the `<g>` element and putting the transform on the `<g>` element.

Comment: mmh, the transform on an svg element happens in the coordinate space of its parent element, whereas the transformation in a contained g element will happen in the coordinate space of the svg element itself. this becomes visible when you use a viewBox on the inner svg element.
So you should put the g element which holds the transformation around the svg element.

Comment: viewBox applies to children only. viewBox and transform together make this more obvious.

Comment: right, but your last sentence says you  achieve the same result when placing the transformation on a g element inside the svg element. But to achieve the same result for the exact same values in the transform attribute, you should put the g element around the svg element...

Comment: Right, it would make it simpler for people to understand that way round. Updated.