# getBoundingClientRect() returns wrong values for nested SVGs in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg, microsoft-edge

I am having some issues with the size of the svg-dom element being larger than it's given size if an element inside it is larger, or set to a different position. I have made a js fiddle where you can reproduce it. Just inspect it and check the size of svg3. If you do it in chrome it is set to 500px by 500px, in firefox it is set to the svg's given size. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w1gftej0/17/
And here is the code:

```html
   <div style="width:200px;height:70px">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
            <svg id="svg1" width="100%" height="90%">
                <rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="#00001a"></rect>
                <svg id="svg2" width="90%" height="10%" x="10%">
                    <rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="#ff4d4d"></rect>
                </svg>
                <svg id="svg3" width="90%" height="90%" x="10%" y="10%">
                    <rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="#ff4d4d"></rect>
                    <line x1="0%" x2="500px" y1="25%" y2="25%" stroke="#236ce0" />
                    <line x1="50%" x2="50%" y1="0%" y2="500px" stroke="#236ce0" />
                </svg>
                <svg id="svg4" width="10%" height="90%" y="10%">
                    <rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="#ff4d4d"></rect>
                </svg>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This behaviour is causing me quite a lot of headaches during my development, is there any fixes that makes chrome/edge behave like firefox? I do realize that if all elements inside the svg are smaller, this issue doesn't exist. However, with the application i am working on, this completely breaks the functionality if for some reason the svg element is larger. (I am using getBoundingClientRect to calculate mouse positions). 
I would love any tips as to how to handle this.

This is a follow up to a question i asked about 2 months ago: [Nested SVG's width height set in % not working in chrome or edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52876222/nested-svgs-width-height-set-in-not-working-in-chrome-or-edge)

edit:

Possibly a bug, reported it here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=914324

Comment: It's generally not recommended to use height / width for defining SVG sizes....that's what the `viewbox` is for.

Comment: You might need to explain further what you think is wrong.  If I change the `width` and `height` attributes of svg3 using the inspector, I see the same result in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau i expanded the example in fiddle so that it logs the size to console. For me it says 500/500 in chrome and 180/56.69 in firefox.

Comment: @Paulie_D I am not sure i understand how you want me to code the sizes. As far as i know(fairly new to svg's) the viewbox controls what is visible inside the viewport, my problem is that the svg(viewport) element get's larger than it's set size in chrome, but not in firefox.

Comment: @Haldor I don't see any change to your snippet or the linked fiddle.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau fixed the link

Comment: It looks like a bug in Chrome.  It is rendering correctly, it just seems to be returning the wrong values from `getBoundingClientRect()`. Please report the bug at crbug.com

Comment: If you do, please post the bug link here for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau ok, another way you can see it is if you inspect element and look at the outline. Reported it at crbug.com. Thank you.

Comment: I observed the same bug: it is somehow related to the screens. I have two distinct screen: in one screen everything work fine, in th emain screen getBoundingRect make an error with a ration of  1.25 on both axis (and no, the two screen do not have such ration size difference)